# How to change the back ground color of an active link

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried all I can, but does not seem to work. I want that when a user clicks on one of the navigating menus, the background color of the active menu the user is actively viewing should have a different color.

Comment: Please try to google before asking. Read [ask]

Comment: I guess i would not be posting ,if i had found a solution of my problem from google .

Comment: @EbongScofield then maybe your question isn't clear enough. Please define what is *the current active link* and what cannot be found in css references about it.

Comment: Did you mean, it should have changed background color after clicking on it or when you hover hover it.

An active link means you have clicked the link , and landed on respective page. In that case, pseudo class :visited would do.

Comment: Literally the first link when googling "css active link" answers your question as it is right now

Comment: I mean  to say when a user clicks on of   the menu links.The background color of the current active link  he she is currently viewing  to change color.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use selector of your link in css e.g.

```css
a{
    color: blue;
}

a:active{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <a href="google.com" class="">That's your link</a>
</p>
```

Comment: bro i have tried  all that but does not seem to work .I want that when a user clicks on one of the navigating menus, the background of the active menu should  have a different color .

Comment: That comment should be in the question, as it specifies the desired action.

Answer (score 0):

This is an commmon problem, to do this you just need to add an :active element to the element you want to change the below code could help:

```css
a:active{
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>codedamn HTML Playground</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://demo.com" target="_blank">DEMO</a>
    </body>
</html>
```